# Git. How can I add folders and files under version control

Tags: windows-7, git

I've forked a remote Git repository, so I get it on my PC.

I've added two folders and two files but Git doens't recognize commit.

I try to launch this command:

```
git commit -m "my message"
```

but my folders and files are under section:

"Untracked files".

So, for Git there are nothing to commit.

I've installed Git on Windows 7 and as development environment I use Spring Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `git add` them first. Or call `git commit -a` so they get added automatically. You always need to add new files before they are staged and then you can commit.

Comment: Dear, yes! I've jumped git add phases. Thank you very much

Comment: I forgot that quite often as well when I started with git. You get used to it later.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll accept your answer but I must wait for 10 minutes. Thanks again.